# Variadic template templates with data pointers

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a class template which takes a type and a pointer to a variable of that type:

```
template <typename arg_t, arg_t* storage>
class Value;
```

I have a second class template which takes a variable number of templates of the first class:

```
template <typename... arg_t>
class ValueList;
```

I want to make it so that only types of class template Value can be used as arguments to ValueList by partial specialization.  This is what I'd expect to work:

```
template <typename... arg_t, arg_t*... storage>
class ValueList<Value<arg_t, storage>...>;
```

In Visual C++ 2013, I get the error: `'arg_t*': parameter pack cannot be expanded in this context`.  Note that this kind of expansion works for templates that only take types, IE this...

```
template <typename...>
class A;

template <template <typename, typename> class B, typename... C, typename... D>
class A<B<C, D>...> {};
```

...is valid.  What makes this case any different, and what is the correct syntax that will achieve the desired effect?

Usage:

```
int a;
float b;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ValueList<Value<int, &a>, Value<float, &b> > list;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us usage of this type? However, it works in gcc/clang for me.

Comment: @ForEveR Added usage to OP.

Comment: @ForEveR I just tried it in MinGW and it works there too.  Is Visual C++ really that behind?

Comment: As written `Value<int,&a>` doesn't work with clang 3.3 either. non-const expression error, just fyi (and I somewhat expected that).

Comment: @WhozCraig Should have clarified that I solved that issue by declaring the variables in a different scope.

Comment: Writing a type check using nested recursive template structs works in Visual C++, but it's not as elegant of a solution as I'm looking for.

Comment: @NmdMystery yeah, I tried it in clang properly declared as you have it above, and it still won't work. Well, it will "work", but only through the base-non-specialized `ValueList`; the specialization will compile, but not be utilized. Pretty sure I have it right. Interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to §14.1/15 the code in the string

```
template <typename... arg_t, arg_t*... storage>
```

is not allowed:

> A template parameter pack that is a pack expansion shall not expand a
>   parameter pack declared in the same template-parameter-list. [
>   Example:
>
> ```
> // ...
>
> template<class... T, T... Values> struct static_array;// error: Values expands template type parameter
>                                                       // pack T within the same template parameter list
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments suggested a nested template check, so here is an implementation for that.  Just for fun, I used an empty struct called `MyTag` which only `class Value<>` should inherit from as a marker for being a legal parameter.  I couldn't think of a more concise way to do it.

```
using namespace std;

struct MyTag {};

template <typename arg_t, arg_t* storage>
class Value : MyTag {};

//Iterate throught the list, checking each parameter
template<typename F, typename... T>
struct CheckValuePack{
  static const bool value = is_base_of<MyTag,F>::value &&
                            CheckValuePack<T...>::value;
  typedef enable_if<is_base_of<MyTag,F>::value &&
                     CheckValuePack<T...>::value
                     > Checked;
};

//Check the last parameter
template<typename F>
struct CheckValuePack<F>{
  static const bool value = is_base_of<MyTag,F>::value;
};

template <typename... T>
class ValueList {
  CheckValuePack<T...> checked; //perform the check
};

int a;
float b;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      ValueList<Value<int, &a>, Value<float, &b> > list;
      //ValueList<Value<int, &a>, Value<float, &b>, int > list; //compile time error
      return 0;
}
```

Note that `CheckValuePack<T...>` in `ValueList<>` could also be inherited.